# Swiper slider not working unless page is resized

Tags: javascript, jquery, swiper.js

I'm trying to add the [Swiper](http://idangero.us/swiper) plugin to one of my page. What I'm trying to achieve is to integrate get the carousal slider over here http://idangero.us/swiper/demos/05-slides-per-view.html

**HTML**

```
<div class="swiper-container">
  <div class="swiper-wrapper">
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 1</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 2</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 3</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 4</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 5</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 6</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 7</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 8</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 9</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 10</div>
  </div>
  <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
var swiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
  pagination: '.swiper-pagination',
  slidesPerView: 3,
  paginationClickable: true,
  spaceBetween: 30,
  // Navigation arrows
  nextButton: '.swiper-button-next',
  prevButton: '.swiper-button-prev',
});
```

When i add it to a fiddle it works but when i add to my html page, the swiper doesnt work until i open firebug or resize the page (http://vidznet.com/ng1/swiper/swipe.html) Im not sure if its conflicting when initializing because There are no errors in the console.

After spending some time I thought it might be a jquery issue and wrapped the coding inside a

> pagebeforecreate

```
 $(document).on( "pagebeforecreate", "#new_",function( event ) {
```

but still the same,

I also added the below code

```
swiper.updateContainerSize();
```

which is supposed to update the container size, but still not working.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: adding `observer: true, observeParents: true` to the config object resolved the issue for me (using v4.1.6 of swiper)

Comment: @Isaiahiroko Worked for me too.

Comment: Nice Catch. Had this issue but never noticed resizing makes it work.

Answer (score 53):

Swiper's sliders, in order to work properly, requires you to either:

- Initialize them when they are visible
- Update them when they get visible
- Enable observer parameters

  - [`observer: true`](https://swiperjs.com/swiper-api#param-observer)
  - [`observeParents: true`](https://swiperjs.com/swiper-api#param-observeParents)

As stated by [@Isaiahiroko](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43770106/swiper-slider-not-working-unless-page-is-resized#comment86710292_43770106) and Swiper's creator (on [this issue](https://github.com/nolimits4web/Swiper/issues/2276#issuecomment-339918354)), executing one of the mentioned topics will solve your issue, for sure!

Comment: observer: true, solved my issue, As i was using vuejs, and need to fetch data after the slider been initialized.
thanks.

Comment: should be the accepted answer here, this solves all update issues you may run into on css calculations.

Answer (score 24):

Also i had face this problem , i think you should add two lines (Parameters) in the Java Script of swipper ,

```
var galleryThumbs = new Swiper('.gallery-thumbs', {
            observer: true,
            observeParents: true,
            loop: true,
            spaceBetween: 10,
            slidesPerView: 4,
            freeMode: true,
            watchSlidesVisibility: true,
            watchSlidesProgress: true,
        })
```

Where **"obeserver : true"** And **"observerParents : true"** are the parameters which effects your swipper to be work properly. This make my swipper working in properly ! Hope you get done !

Comment: @Isaiahiroko commented this on the OP's question

Answer (score 13):

Use this code:

```
swiper.update();
```

Comment: In my case, it is React-based app with animations when swipeable content first appears, I had to call it with a small delay in `setTimeout`

Answer (score 3):

I tried below code it worked for me my swiper was present inside a tab, when my document is loaded swipper was not working unless and unless I resize the screen,so i tried below code it worked

```
var swiper = new Swiper('#upcoming-appointments', {
        slidesPerView: 1,
        spaceBetween: 30,
        loop: true,
        pagination: {
            el: '.swiper-pagination',
            clickable: true,
        },
        navigation: {
            nextEl: '.swiper-button-next',
            prevEl: '.swiper-button-prev',
        },
//<---Add this two lines in your code-->   
       observer: true,  
       observeParents: true,
    });
```

Answer (score 3):

**For Angular:**

Add `(swiper)="onSwiper($event)"` to your `swiper` component.

`<swiper (swiper)="onSwiper($event)"></swiper>`

And in your `.ts` add:

```
onSwiper(swiper) {
  swiper.update();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This solved my problem

1. Add this lines in your swiper initialization

   `observer: true,`
   `observeParents: true,`

   your initialization will look like this

   ```
   var swiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
       pagination: '.swiper-pagination',
       slidesPerView: 3,
       observer: true,
       observeParents: true,
       paginationClickable: true,
       spaceBetween: 30,
       // Navigation arrows
       nextButton: '.swiper-button-next',
       prevButton: '.swiper-button-prev',
   });
   ```
2. Then, update your swiper instance with

   ```
   swiper.update()
   ```

Answer (score 1):

you could try :

```
$(window).on({
   load: function(){
      $(this).trigger('resize');
    } 
  });
```

though it's a bit of a stickytape solution.

Comment: could you try $(window).trigger('resize'); in a setTimeout function with a one second delay? - not as a solution but just as a test. I suspect as you do that it's to do with loading sequences

Comment: No need for dependence on jQuery: use `window.onload = function() { // Some stuff };`

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue,
in my case, I replace the class name `swiper-container` with `swiper` in the main container

Comment: wow, i can't believe i got stuck on this stupid mistake. thank you!

Answer (score 0):

For anyone reading this, and using version 6.x of Swiper, you need to import the additional modules (like Navigation, Pagination, etc.) for them to work.

```
// core version + navigation, pagination modules:
import Swiper, { Navigation, Pagination } from 'swiper';

// configure Swiper to use modules
Swiper.use([Navigation, Pagination]);

// init Swiper:
const swiper = new Swiper(...);
```

Comment: Here is the list of every module that you shall import https://swiperjs.com/api/#custom-build

Comment: Even in newest swiper (and thats some years) the same bug remains, when using lazy and more images at time, they are not loaded till resize or till interaction with slider, no observer or anything mentioned above works, only way around is to use simple index and load first few images in normal way, all others in lazy way.

Answer (score 0):

I had the similar issue,

in my case adding `rebuildOnUpdate: true` helped
(you may also need `observer: true` as mentioned above)

p.s. I'm working with `react-id-swiper` and `swiper`

Answer (score -2):

Only add

```
autoplay: {delay:3000,disableOnInteraction:false}
```

to parameters